# JavaScript - How do I execute certain query from dropdown select?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I'd like to simplify my code by execute some certain query based on what user choose

the idea is user will show the query based on Base + group by from this query when they visit the page for the first time. but next, they can decide what data they'd like to see from the dropdown below

```
  //Base
  $Material = "SELECT MATERIAL, COUNT(MATERIAL) AS 'TOTAL' FROM `khitable` ";
  $StorageLocation = "SELECT SLOC ,COUNT(SLOC) AS 'TOTAL' FROM `khitable`";
  $VerifStock = "SELECT VERIF_STOCK ,COUNT(VERIF_STOCK) AS 'TOTAL' FROM `khitable`";

  //Tipe Pipa
  $ERW = "WHERE MATERIAL LIKE '%ER%'";
  $SP = "WHERE MATERIAL LIKE '%SP%'";
  $ACC = "WHERE MATERIAL LIKE '%ACC%'";

  //Status Pengerjaan
  $FG = "AND MATERIAL NOT LIKE '%SF-%'";
  $WIP = "AND MATERIAL LIKE '%SF-%'";

  //Ketersediaan
  $SO = "AND SO_NUMBER NOT LIKE '%605%'";
  $Buffer = "AND SO_NUMBER LIKE '%605%'";
  $FS = "AND MATERIAL LIKE '%-FS%";

  //Group By
  $GroupMaterial = "GROUP BY MATERIAL";
  $GroupSLOC = "GROUP BY SLOC";
  $GroupVerifStock = "GROUP BY VERIF_STOCK";
```

and the next user could be able to choose what data to show from the dropdown list below

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s4">      
    <select class="validate">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih pilihan anda</option>
      <option value="1">Finish Good</option>
      <option value="2">Semi Finish (WIP)</option>
    </select>
    <label >Pilih Berdasarkan Status Pengerjaan</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s4">      
    <select class="validate">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih pilihan anda</option>
      <option value="1">Sales Order</option>
      <option value="2">Buffer</option>
      <option value="3">Free Stock</option>
    </select>
    <label >Pilih Berdasarkan Status Ketersediaan</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

so there are 2 dropdown, and user only see based on what they been choose on dropdown list. what I don't understand yet is to do so on my code. thanks for anyone help here.

p.s. : data were suppose to viewed from database, based on what the query shown

Comment: I see form fields but no form element. Is the user submitting a form or are you using javacript to invoke further actions?

Comment: use dropdown change event in jquery and run ajax to call you php file, inside your php file fire query as per you selection value passed in ajax.

Comment: can you give an example about fire the query and passed the value in ajax? i'm quite new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php:

```
//Base
 $select["Material"] = "SELECT MATERIAL, COUNT(MATERIAL) AS 'TOTAL' FROM `khitable` ";
 $select["StorageLocation"] = "SELECT SLOC ,COUNT(SLOC) AS 'TOTAL' FROM `khitable`";
 $select["VerifStock"] = "SELECT VERIF_STOCK ,COUNT(VERIF_STOCK) AS 'TOTAL' FROM `khitable`";

 //Tipe Pipa
$where["ERW"] = "WHERE MATERIAL LIKE '%ER%'";
$where["SP"] = "WHERE MATERIAL LIKE '%SP%'";
$where["ACC"] = "WHERE MATERIAL LIKE '%ACC%'";

//Status Pengerjaan
$and1["FG"] = "AND MATERIAL NOT LIKE '%SF-%'";
$and1["WIP"] = "AND MATERIAL LIKE '%SF-%'";

//Ketersediaan
$and2["SO"] = "AND SO_NUMBER NOT LIKE '%605%'";
$and2["Buffer"] = "AND SO_NUMBER LIKE '%605%'";
$and2["FS"] = "AND MATERIAL LIKE '%-FS%";

//Group By
$group["GroupMaterial"] = "GROUP BY MATERIAL";
$group["GroupSLOC"] = "GROUP BY SLOC";
$group["GroupVerifStock"] = "GROUP BY VERIF_STOCK";

$query = $select[$_GET["query_select"]]." ".
         $where[$_GET["query_where"]]." ".$and1[$_GET["query_and1"]].
         " ".$and1[$_GET["query_and2"]]." ".$group[$_GET["query_group"]];
```

html:

```
<form action="yourscript.php" method="get">
<!-- here is your form elements for material,storagelocation etc -->
  .................
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s4">      
    <select class="validate" name="query_and1">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih pilihan anda</option>
      <option value="FG">Finish Good</option>
      <option value="WIP">Semi Finish (WIP)</option>
    </select>
    <label >Pilih Berdasarkan Status Pengerjaan</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s4">      
    <select class="validate" name="query_and2">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih pilihan anda</option>
      <option value="SO">Sales Order</option>
      <option value="Buffer">Buffer</option>
      <option value="FS">Free Stock</option>
    </select>
    <label >Pilih Berdasarkan Status Ketersediaan</label>
  </div>
</div>
 ............
 </form>
```

i hope you understand an idea

Comment: is it possible even when the and option are not choosen at all?

Comment: yes, they will be presented as an empty string. but there must be `<select name="query_select">` and `<select name="query_where">` element in form which must be selected to build right $query

Answer (score 0):

check below example link for more details how to submit data using ajax and get the result

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp